# Computers can't access each other when both of them connect to Apple NAT64 hotspot

Tags: macos, ipv6, nat, ios

We have an iOS App on App Store. To submit a new version after Jun 1st, 2016, we have to support an “IPv6-only network” according to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a).

We referred to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16), upgraded a Mac Mini to El Capitan and set it to a NAT64 hotspot. This Mac Mini uses Ethernet to connect to Internet, and shared its Internet connection to Wi-Fi.

To use our product, user has to install both our iOS App and Mac App, and put them into the same network (something like iPhone is on `192.168.0.1` and Mac is on `192.168.0.2` in IPv4 world). These two Apps need to access internet, which is working without any problem in this environment.

```
iPhone--(Wi-Fi)--\
                  --Mac mini--(ethernet)--Router----Internet
Mac-----(Wi-Fi)--/
```

The problem is our iOS App (running on iPhone, acting as a TCP client) can’t access our Mac App (running on a Mac Book Pro in this case, acting as a TCP server) in this IPv6/NAT64 environment.

After some testing, we believe the problem is on the Apple NAT64 side, because on the iPhone we can’t even ping the Mac (we tried use another MacBook Air to replace the iPhone, same result). The weird thing is sometimes (normally happened after we keep pinging Mac for a while) it works. And once it works, it always works. But if the iPhone and Mac just connected to the NAT64, it seems not working as always. Did anyone ever face to situation like this? **Is it a Apple NAT64 bug? or just a configuration issue? How can I make it work?**

#### More information for your information:

`ifconfig` on Mac mini which has a NAT64 running on:

```
en1: flags=8b63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 6c:40:08:c0:a7:9e
    inet6 fe80::6e40:8ff:fec0:a79e%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
    inet 169.254.156.123 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether ae:87:a3:21:fb:64
    inet6 2001:2:0:aab1::1 prefixlen 64
    inet6 fe80::ac87:a3ff:fe21:fb64%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:ac87:a3ff:fe21:fb64 prefixlen 64 autoconf
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:30d2:e0e9:360c:2bb3 prefixlen 64 deprecated autoconf temporary
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:2d34:d3ae:a433:b6c8 prefixlen 64 deprecated autoconf temporary
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:d0a1:a2e5:5a20:3105 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

ifconfig on MacBook Pro which acts as TCP server:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 78:31:c1:d5:cd:6a
    inet6 fe80::7a31:c1ff:fed5:cd6a%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:7a31:c1ff:fed5:cd6a prefixlen 64 autoconf
    inet6 2001:2::aab1:fc82:1afd:d541:33cb prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary
    inet 169.254.25.56 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Logs on iPhone that shows the IP addesses:

```
name = en0, addr = fe80::14f8:dd59:a2e9:8f65, scope_id = 3
name = en0, addr = 2001:2::aab1:10d8:247a:a7b9:3c8d, scope_id = 0
name = en0, addr = 2001:2::aab1:2560:58b7:2b6c:ce8b, scope_id = 0
name = en0, addr = 169.254.228.221
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't access"? Are you using a service discovery protocol (e.g. Bonjour) to discover the service your Mac app provides? If so, which service discovery protocol? When you connect or ping, are you connecting by name, by IPv4 address, or by IPv6 address? If by name, is it a .local name, or a public FQDN? If by address, are you using a link-local address or publicly routable address? Do you know if multicast works on your network? Is ARP working? Is NBP working?

Comment: Can you from a normal PC or Mac ping anything and get a response on the IPv6 network?

Also please dump the routing tables to see if somehow you are getting bad routes.

Comment: There has never been any guarantee that two devices connected to the same hotspot could reach each other, only that both devices can reach servers on the Internet. You have to be prepared to use a relay server somewhere on the Internet if the two devices can't reach each other directly. You may be able to sometimes get the connection to work where it otherwise wouldn't be simultaneously sending traffic from each device to the other, which is probably what you are accomplishing by accident the times it works. Typically a server on the Internet directs the coordination between the two machines.

Comment: @Spiff, no, we use IP address directly. A send its IP to web server on Internet. B access web server to get A's IP.

Comment: @KyleSponable, thanks for the routing table tip! I checked routing table on the Mac mini (NAT64) and it looks just fine. There's no way I can check routing table on iPad (TCP client). I found an App called "routing table", but it can't run on iPad. I also tried "iNet Tools", but it does not support IPv6 at all. I found once I ping iPad from MacBook Pro (it works), then I can now ping MacBook Pro from iPad.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmm still sounds like you are having an issue establishing a path to the server on the network usually its a routing table issue